# Motorbikes in Thailand and Laos

Tags: southeast-asia, motorcycles, laos, thailand, rental

Does anyone know of a place to hire motorbikes in Thailand, say Bangkok or Chiang Mai, and ride them into Laos and back? The trip will be self-guided and should take no longer than two weeks.

Comment: that's a good loop you can do with you motobike from Chiang Mai: http://www.budget.co.th/images/world/worldclass_mae_eng.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to hire motorbikes in Bangkok and Chiang Mai. I haven't done this myself but some friends did. It costs about 200-800 baht per day to hire one depending on the type of motorcycle you get. It might make sense to buy one from an expat or a another traveller, then sell it when (if?) you go back to Thailand. You will definitely need to have [an IDP](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/441/are-international-driving-licences-really-necessary-for-any-country) to drive around in Bangkok as police keep a watch out for tourists.

The problem I foresee with your plan of driving to Laos could be that many motorcycle rental places in Thailand retain your passport. You could try convincing them to leave just a copy of your passport but for long-term hires they may not agree.  You also need to have paperwork to cross the Thai-Lao border on bike.

Those are the basics. [GT Rider](http://www.gt-rider.com/) is a good place to start your research on the exact documentation you need to cross the border, the kinds of motorcycles usually available for hire, maps, et al.

Comment: Thanks for that info Ankur, gives me confidence befroe heading over. I have check the GT but they dont have any specific places to hire or detail if they will let us take them over the border. Looks like i will have to get my negotiation boots on.

Comment: @Peter: See http://www.gt-rider.com/maps-of-thailand-laos-maps/border-documents for list of documents need to cross border. A good place for specific places to hire would be the [GT Rider forum](http://www.gt-rider.com/thailand-motorcycle-forum/).

Answer (score 3):

I hired a scooter in Chiang Mai for 200 baht a day. However, an accident there might cost you about 4000-5000 baht. You would be very lucky if the damage is minor and you are quoted a damage cost below 4000 baht. No license is needed, just a passport will do. They will keep your passport when you rent the bike.

The rented motorbike does not usually have enough milage to bring you from Bangkok/Chiang Mai to Laos. Furthermore, I highly recommend against travelling to Laos as the roads in the Laos section of your journey may be bumpy and not well-suited for your rented motorbike.

Answer (score 1):

Hiring a motorbike in Thailand isn't a problem. 
From THB 200 per day of THB 2,000 per month you'll 'have' one.

As another poster stated that a rental-company will retain your passport: that's not allowed. They are allowed to make a copy of your passport incl. visa page and Immigration Departure Card.

The problem is 'entering Laos'; most probably no rental-company will allow you to take the rental-bike into Laos. Temporary import of a vehicle into Laos, Cambodia is only possible if you have the original green/blue book on hand OR if you have a written permission from the owner of the vehicle (there's a special form for that), but the rental company will be reluctant/refusing its cooperation.