# Driving in U.S. (Hawaii) with EU license written in Czech

Tags: usa, driving, languages, driving-licenses, eu-citizens

I have a European driving license which is completely written in Czech (see photos below). Can I use it for driving in the U.S. (I will go to Hawaii for 3 weeks), or do I have to obtain another document where the information is written in English?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are international driving licences really necessary for any country?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/441/are-international-driving-licences-really-necessary-for-any-country)

Comment: @Karlson I had read that question before I posted mine. However, Australian citizen has no problem with the DL being written in Czech, and no answer there addresses this issue.

Comment: If you read the accepted answer it states that for driving in the US it is recommended that you get an IDP.  I could also link http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4901/are-there-any-legal-requirements-for-renting-a-car-in-the-us-as-a-foreigner which deals with similar issue

Comment: @Karlson I read it. The site linked there does not treat US states seperately, while the legislation is state-dependent. Therefore I ask a more specific question which does not seem to be covered by that one.

Comment: http://www1.honolulu.gov/csd/vehicle/faqs_dl.htm#oos_drive

Comment: Thanks! That is what I need, and as you see, it is not covered by the other question ;)

Comment: It is because while IDP is recommended it's not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Karlson pointed out already, the Hawaiian law does not require you to have an international drivers license. Additionally, your drivers license is rather obvious in terms of clarity to understand what it means.

However, I would still highly recommend you to get a IDL. You might run into a policeman who simply wants the documents written in English. Since IDLs are normally easy, cheap and fast to get, it should be a good thing to have to minimize trouble when getting in conflict with the law.

Also, it should be another point of concern where you get your car from. If you rent a car, you might want to check with your car rental company if they want you to present an IDL.