# Do Europeans require a visa to visit USA?

Tags: usa, visas, maltese-citizens

I will be staying for 2months in the USA, do I require a visa since I am a citizen of Malta, which is part of the European Union?

Comment: Being part of EU is completely irrelevant in case of US visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [usembassy.gov](http://malta.usembassy.gov/frequently_asked_questions.html):

> A.  Effective December 30, 2008, Maltese citizens are eligible to
>   travel to the U.S. without a visa under the Visa Waiver Program if the
>   following conditions are met:
>
> - The visit is less than 90 days
> - The visit is for tourism or business
> - The traveler holds a valid biometric passport
> - The traveler registers for and receives an approved travel authorization, or ESTA (Electronic System for Travel Authorization),
>     by entering their travel details at https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov  at least
>     72 hours prior to commencing travel
> - The traveler has a valid return ticket
> - The traveler has no prior legal convictions.

Comment: Thanks really helpful! Do you also know where I can check regarding license. A friend of mine told me normal license was accepted some years ago, but I want to check just in case as Im thinking maybe of hiring a car for couple of days.

Comment: @rikket see this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4901/2560

Comment: *"The visit is for tourism or business"* What else?

Comment: Visits for terrorism are not allowed without a visa! Seriously, I think the last two options left are diplomatic and medical.

Comment: @feklee you cannot work. By business they mean to go to conferences or something like that

Comment: @Dirty-flow I am actually going to be working there for 2 months but it is all voluntary and I won't earn any money (in exchange for food and accommodation)

Comment: @feklee There are visits for medical treatment, bereavement, etc