# Is an IDP required to drive on an American license in Bangladesh?

Tags: usa, driving-licenses, bangladesh

If one has an American license, is that sufficient to be able to legally drive in Bangladesh ? 
I read this about Australia https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/5806/4584 but found nothing for Bangladesh. And this post https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/451/4584 made me ask my question

Comment: Besides legality, if you are not used to drive in any developing country (& China), just don't think about it. You will definitely run into big mess.

Answer (score 2):

Your [post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/441/are-international-driving-licences-really-necessary-for-any-country/451#451) is pretty apt. I have driven all around Asia without a license actually. 
But, the good thing is Bangladesh accepts [International Driving Permit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit). 
So, that's what you should apply for (to drive there).

Comment: So...you're saying the OP **should** get an IDP?

Comment: yes! Answer edited.

Comment: -1. Your "This post" is the same as I posed in my question ! (And this post ..made me..). So, to me, it isn't apt. I will not engage in illegal/corrupt practices. An IDP is a license translated from a native language to English. Mine is in English. So, I circle back to my original question :If one has an American license, is that sufficient to be able to legally drive in Bangladesh ?

Comment: I was actually referring to your post. It wasn't so obvious after the edits done to my answer. You are wrong about IDP. It isn't a mere translation of your license, it is a permit. I have updated my answer with the Wiki Link to IDP, so you can learn a bit more about it.

Comment: I looked up the wiki and the image in there says Bangladesh dont honor the 1949 convention (IDP). And the AAA page (http://www.aaa.com/vacation/idpapplc.html) says IDP is indeed valid in B'desh. Guess I will never know till I get pulled over in B'desh :(

Comment: @happybuddha where did you read that "An IDP is a license translated from a native language to English."? It's translated in many different languages actually. As shocking as it may sounds to you, English isn't spoken everywhere.