# Acquiring an international driving permit in the US

Tags: us-citizens, driving-licenses

After reviewing "[Are international driving licences really necessary for any country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/441/82)" it seems like it might be worth my while to look into acquiring an International Driving Permit.

I'm having some difficulty determining exactly how one does so, however.

What are the requirements for obtaining an International Driving Permit as a US citizen, and where should I go to take care of the process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In many countries your US drivers license will be sufficient, and you will not require an International Driving Permit - especially in other countries that speak English. That said, obviously having an IDP will never hurt, and they are relatively cheap to obtain.

The IDP is not in itself a license, it's basically a translation of your existing license.  You will need to present both your IDP and your regular US license any time you are asked for your license.

If you do choose to get one, the two recognized places in the US are the [AAA](http://www.aaa.com/vacation/idpf.html) and the [National Automobile Club](http://www.thenac.com/idp_faqs.htm). Exact details are at those links, but basically it involves either going into your nearest AAA office, or sending in an application to either club.

Comment: I've applied for and received on the spot a International Driver's License at an AAA office before, and it's not necessary to be a member to do so.