# International driver's permit expired in the USA

Tags: international-travel, italian-citizens

I'm not an American citizen but I was here as a student. I'm Italian and my international driver's permit expires in April. I came here in April 2015 and for 20 days I'm uncovered. What happens to me if I'll be stopped and my IDP is expired?

Comment: To the close voters, yes they're a student, but that's just the background, the actual issue is the validity of driving without an IDP. Don't close because of the extraneous information.

Answer (score 2):

The expiration date that counts is your normal driving license.  The IDP is nothing but a standardized translation of your license.  As long as your Italian license is still valid, you are OK.

Comment: Omg really? The only thing I can do is show my Italian driver license, my passport and the IDP? Should I apply for an American one?? I'm so scared. I don't feel comfortable driving when I'm not allowed to!

Comment: Many people mistakenly call the IDP a license, it is not, it is just an international agreed upon translation.  Your home license is what says you can drive, the IDP lets police know which part says what.  Many states require residents to obtain a local driver's license, so maybe something you should look into.

Comment: @Tom Students are generally not required to get a local license.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - each state's laws are different, what Nevada requires is not the same as what Florida requires.  And we don't know what state the OP studies in and since some states DO mandate a local license, my advice stands as is.

Answer (score 1):

See [How can I determine if I need an International Driving Permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48778/how-can-i-determine-if-i-need-an-international-driving-permit?rq=1) - it's generally only required when the script is different to yours.

Source: NZ citizen, and have used a NZ license without an IDP in the USA to rent and drive cars on several occasions, and have even been checked by police.