# EU driver's license valid in the Philippines

Tags: driving, driving-licenses, philippines

I'm from Belgium and I have a Belgian drivers license (for just over 1 year).

In December I will be going to the Philippines. Do I need an international driver's license or can I use my Belgian one?

Comment: Note: See [What is an International Driver's License?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18894/6188) for a description of what an `International Drivers License` actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LTO is the government body in Philippines responsible for licensing drivers and registering vehicles. [See the official LTO FAQ](http://www.lto.gov.ph/frequently-asked-questions/license-permit.html#slider):

> 2. I have a valid foreign driver’s license. Can I use it in the Philippines?
>
> Yes, 90 days from date of arrival.
>
> 3. Can I convert my foreign driver’s license into Philippine driver’s license?
>
> Yes. If valid, no exams. If expired subject to written / practical
>   exams. Click the link for more information. (Non-Professional Driver's
>   License, Professional Driver's License)

This is also not an easy country to drive, due to poor road quality and huge traffic jams in big cities.

Comment: Getting a local licence used to be quite easy but it seems to be getting harder.  The last time I tried, they wanted a residence permit.  I gave up and used my UK licence.  At best, you will spend a long time in the office and leave with an unimpressive receipt.  The actual licence may arrive months later.

Comment: Following the non-professional link shows a requirement that you have been there for one month and will stay at least one year.  See qualification 5.  So, not quite residence but not just a holiday either.  I get leave to stay a year without visa as my wife is Filipino.  That did not seem to be sufficient.

Comment: @badjohn I had the same problem, [but solved it](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137563/how-to-legally-drive-in-the-philippines-as-a-foreigner/137579#137579)

Comment: Please, [check this question and accepted answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137563/how-to-legally-drive-in-the-philippines-as-a-foreigner/137579) for well-researched information on this topic.