# Can I drive in the USA with a French drivers license?

Tags: driving, driving-licenses

Question is pretty much in the title. I have a French drivers' license, and will be driving in the USA in a couple weeks. Is it accepted as-is, or must I get a translation? What preparation do I need to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are international driving licences really necessary for any country?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/441/are-international-driving-licences-really-necessary-for-any-country)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [USA.gov](https://www.usa.gov/visitors-driving), it appears it's very much dependent on which states you plan on driving in:

> If you are a visitor from outside the United States and Canada who
>   plans to drive in the U.S., check with the motor vehicle department of
>   each state you will drive in for its requirements.  Some of the states
>   will require an International Driving Permit (IDP) in addition to a
>   valid license from your own country.

That's a bit vague though, and doesn't clarify the language thing. Fortunately, [justlanded.com](https://www.justlanded.com/english/United-States/USA-Guide/Travel-Leisure/Driving-Licence) covers this:

> Tourists may drive in the US for up to a year with a foreign driving
>   licence, provided the issuing country is party to the 1949 Geneva
>   Convention on Road Traffic (see art. 1 and art. 25 para. 1) or to the
>   Convention on the Regulation of Inter-American Automotive Traffic
>   (Washington, 1943); most countries are contracting parties.

(Good news, [France is party to the 1949 convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit)!)

They go on to say:

> If your foreign licence doesn’t contain a photograph or is written in
>   a language other than English, it’s wise (but not mandatory) to obtain
>   an International Driver’s Permit (IDP). Always carry your foreign
>   licence as well as your IDP. Without an IDP it may be necessary to
>   obtain a certified English translation of your foreign driving
>   licence, usually obtainable from your country’s embassy in the US.

Hope that helps clarify things.

Comment: My experience in California with Budget was that they were fine with my German licence and did not want the IDP I had with me.