# Can I drive a car in Dubai with an IDP issued in Pakistan?

Tags: driving, driving-licenses, uae

Can I drive a car in Dubai with an international driving permit issued in Pakistan? Does it matter if I'm driving a rental car or a friend's car?

I hold a valid driving license from Pakistan, that license is valid for both car and motorcycle.

Comment: More relevant than the issuing location of the IDP is what driving license(s) you hold. (ie what country and what categories)

Comment: Close voting as unclear until you tell us what liscence you have.

Comment: @CMaster Updated the information, could we perhaps reopen this?

Comment: looks ok to me, voted reopen. Have to see what everyone else thinks.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/441/are-international-driving-licences-really-necessary-for-any-country?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to rent a car, then the short answer is "Yes"! You'll be able to rent a car with an IDP from Pakistan.

Then, if you want to drive your friends' car, you need to ensure that their car insurance contract is properly covering you as a driver which is apparently not really common there.

If you have a residence permit, you'll need a UAE driving license.

Bring your IDP and your driver licence with you :)

Extract from [the embassy website](http://uae-embassy.ae/Embassies/pk/Content/3504):

> To hire any vehicle you will need to provide a passport copy, credit card and a valid driving licence from your home country, or a valid international driving licence. However, if you have been issued with a residence visa, you will need to have a valid UAE driving licence.

Comment: I inlined the link and formatted the quote with the appropriate markdown environment. [Have a read here to learn how to use markdown.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) Oh, and welcome to the site. Great contributions so far. Come to [the Travel chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) if you're feeling lonely. :)

Comment: Great thanks, sorry to be a pain, need to get used to the formatting :)

Comment: In *no way* are you being a pain. The site takes time to getting used to. So does markdown and the rest of the techy stuff behind it. So far you are doing great. Keep up the good work.