# What consequences may occur as a result of driving a rental car in Austria without an International Drivers Permit?

Tags: legal, car-rentals, austria

I have an Australian (English language) drivers licence, but not an International Drivers Permit.

What consequences may occur as a result of driving a rental car in Austria without an International Drivers Permit?

Comment: This depend on rental car policies. They may require a international driver permit, so you may not get the car. On the other hand, the international permit is mostly used just to have standardized and understandable (language) items on permit.

Comment: I know someone who rented a car in Austria without a IDP which is why I didn't ask about that.  I've already left Australia and understand that I can't get an IDP while abroad.

Comment: FYI don't forget to also pay for [the Austrian "Highway Toll Sticker"](https://www.austria.info/us/basic-facts/getting-there-around/austria-by-car/toll-sticker). Not having the toll sticker can fetch i think 300+ Euro penalty.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/441/are-international-driving-licences-really-necessary-for-any-country

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Rental cars usually have it already.

Comment: re @deviantfan thanks. good to know. when i was renting, i rented in Germany and then drove into Austria. so i did not have the sticker.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Neighbouring countries' rentals won't have the sticker, no. Only what's rented in Austria have them (usually) by default.

Comment: I have **never, ever - ever** had an "international driver's permit" when renting a car in Austria.  Never.  Not once.

Comment: @deviantartfan - good point.  It's infuriating/bizarre that, sometimes when you rent a car in Austria, it does NOT have one!!  I've never understood how that can be!

Answer (score 32):

Your Australian driver's licence is only valid in Austria together with an International Driver's Permit *or* with a translation issued by an authorized Austrian organization, e.g. [ÖAMTC](https://www.oeamtc.at/mitgliedschaft/leistungen/fuehrerscheinuebersetzung-16181676). If you are not able to get an IDP in Australia before you leave, it should be quite easy to get a translation from any of the ÖAMTC offices in Austria. They charge €14 for this service.

Driving without an IDP or a translation will be deemed as driving without a valid license. It is questionable wether the rental company will give you a car at all and if you are caught, the pentalties start with a 363€ fine for a first time offence. Repeating violations may bring you in jail. If you cause an accident, you must also expect the insurance to be void and you will have to cover own and third party damages yourself.

Comment: If anyone wonders about the odd amount of 363 €, that's 5.000 Austrian Schilling (the pre-2002 currency) in Euro. Looks like the fines haven't been raised for a while...

Comment: Do rental companies actually require this in Austria? It's very easy to check the T&C's of a rental company in Vienna airport. If not, then the police doesn't actually care about the IDP.

Comment: As for driving without a license - I don't see how this is different from simply forgetting your license at home. Your license *is* in fact valid for Austria and it *is* valid even without the IDP. All the IDP does is provide an official translation into several languages. Furthermore I'd wager that all Austrian policemen speak fluent English and could read your license without the IDP.

Comment: @JonathanReez I had wondered if in practice Austrian police speak fluent English and would have no trouble with my licence.  But I also wondered if in the event of an accident my travel insurance might not pay, etc.

Comment: @JonathanReez That is the wording of the law (Bundesgesetz über den Führerschein), but I am not sure how violations are handled in practice. The problem is not so much the language on the licence, but for the police to recognize the licence classes, wich are described both in the IDP and the available Austrian translations. If a foreign licence follows the layout and specifications as defined in the Vienna or Geneva Conventions on Road Traffic, it is valid in Austria without an IDP or a translation independent of the issuing language.

Comment: According to my online reading/research, the Austrian rental car companies and police were strict in requiring the IDP and so I got one for my recent trip in 2018.

Comment: I have a Russian driver's license (non-EU, in Cyrillic accompanied by Roman transliteration), and I rented cars all over Europe (including Austria), UK, Cyprus, and was never asked for an IDP. I also got into a couple of accidents, and the insurance worked just fine. This answer is just plain wrong from the practical perspective.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev A Russian driver's licence is valid in Austria without any additional paper work at all. I never said anything else. The question was about an Australian driver's licence.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo that's right, but what's your source for this? Russia is a non-EU country, as is Australia, so what's the difference? (I'm not saying there's none, I'm asking what's the source of your statement) At least Australia's licenses are 100% in Roman script.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev The source is the relevant Austrian law, which has already been quoted here in another answer. The difference between the Russian and the Australian licence is that the Russian document follows international conventions on layout and content, while the Australian does not. This has nothing to do with EU vs non-EU origin.

Comment: "Do rental companies actually require this in Austria?"  I have never, ever, ever, ever been asked for one.   @Tor-EinarJarnbjo , surely your answer is borderline "wrong" in as much as you don't even mention "In practice it is never asked for".   (Caveat - I guess things could have changed dramatically in, say, the last few months.)

Comment: **Exactly** as @JonathanReez says:  "Your license is in fact valid for Austria and it is valid even without the IDP."  End. Of. Story.

Comment: Exactly as it says, from Jonathon's answer, Hertz "recommends" you have one of the International thingies, and the same outcome from the other quoted ones.  IE you don't need one.  "International Driver's Licenses" are a bit of a joke, they're just a piece of paper issued by local motor clubs.

Comment: @Fattie I once sped in Austria and didn't get a fine. So clearly it's totally wrong to claim that there are speed limits in Austria! Great that you could violate the law without consequences, but making statements such as "End of Story" without apparently being capable of reading the actual law is pretty entertaining.

Comment: @Fattie The law is very clear and Sixt's T&Cs have, as I already pointed out. a different wording in German and English. Didn't you read that or did you simply ignore that not even the T&Cs are clear on this point? I also still don't understand why rental companies' T&Cs or practice is relevant. It is not necessarily the rental company's problem if you are later caught and deemed to have been driving without a valid licence.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I do see what you mean; actually the focus of the question is (I suppose) "what will cops in Austria do if you're stopped and don't have an IDL".  (Rather than about the rental companies.)  I guess I just assumed "everyone knows" cops don't care about "IDLs".  I've never, ever had a police officer ask me for one

Answer (score 8):

An International Driving Permit is required by law for Australians in Austria, it does not depend on rental companies' policies in this case.

[Source 1](https://www.austria.info/us/basic-facts/getting-there-around/austria-by-car/driving-regulations-in-austria): Austrian National Tourist Office

> An international drivers license is required and can easily be obtained from your local auto club. The major U.S. rental companies are represented in Austria as are a range of European firms. Many credit cards offer free supplemental rental car insurance, which might let you save on optional car insurance. Check with your credit card company.

[Source 2](https://www.driveaway.com.au/drivingtips/austria#driving_licence): DriveAway Holidays, an Australian self-drive company working in Austria

[Source 3](http://www.austria.org/driving-a-vehicle/): Austrian Embassy in Washington (there was no information on the Canberra embassy's site)

Comment: Note: first link is just about US people (I assume). It is so bad that they do no specify the country. Not all countries needs the international permit.

Comment: My question is: what happens if you don't have one?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Hertz car rental in Vienna airport](https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/location/austria/vienna/VIET50):

> For all Non-European Union renters an International Driving Permit (IDP) is highly recommended. For renters from the US and Canada it is required.

According to [Avis Vienna airport](https://www.avis.com/en/locations/at/vienna/vie):

> Additionally, all driving licenses printed in a non-Roman alphabet must be accompanied by a valid International Driving Permit (IDP).  Both forms of documentation must be issued to the same person, in the same name, and presented together at the time of rental.

Likewise according to [Sixt Vienna airport](https://partner.sixt.de/php/terms/view?liso=AT&rtar=000&view=EPP&tlang=en_GB&style=typo3&ref=offerselect):

> Driver's licenses from non-EU countries (except Switzerland) are accepted if:
>
> - no visa has been entered in the passport.
> - the customer has a visa in his passport and at the time of hire has not been in Europe for longer than 6 months. If he has been in Europe
>   for longer than 6 months, he must present a driver's license from an
>   EU country.
>
> Driver's license printed with non Roman Alphabet (Arabic, Chinese, Japanese, Cyrillic etc) must be complemented by an international driver's license.
>
> For driver's licenses from countries not part of the international driver's license treaty, an official translation of the license must be presented with the original license.

Compare this to [Hertz in Narita airport](https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/location/japan/chiba/NRTT50):

> Japanese law requires that all drivers who do not hold a Japanese driver’s license must hold a country of origin driver's license and an international driving permit issued under the 1949 convention on international road traffic. No other International Driver Permit will be accepted for rentals in Japan.

Or to [Sixt Australia](https://partner.sixt.de/php/terms/view?liso=AU&rtar=000&view=EPP&tlang=en_GB&style=typo3):

> The renter and all approved drivers must be in possession of a full,
> valid driving licence for at least one year. Furthermore, the
> following conditions apply depending on the issuing country of the
> driving licence.
>
> International renters/drivers also need an international
> driver's license and a valid passport.

This leads me to believe that *in practice*, an IDP is not required to rent and drive a car in Austria with an Australian license. If it was, all the rental companies would insist on it in their T&Cs.

Comment: The Hertz rental conditions in German (from Vienna Airport) say something different: 'Alle Anmieter aus Nicht-EU Ländern benötigen zusätzlich zum gültigen nationalen Führerschein eine internationale Fahrerlaubnis (IDP). ' or in English: 'All renters from non-EU countries require in addition to their valid national driver's licence an IDP.' I honestly don't understand how to change the language of the Hertz web page to English.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I would trust the English version more since its an American company. I can see the English version here: https://www.hertz.com/rentacar/reservation/reviewmodifycancel/templates/rentalTerms.jsp?EOAG=VIET50

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo added a reference to Sixt

Comment: Sixt Australia is contradicting themselves if you continue the quote with one more sentence: 'International renters/drivers also need an international driver's license and a valid passport. Driving license printed with non Roman Alphabet (Arabic, Chinese, Japanese, Cyrillic etc) must be complemented by an International driving licence.' I am not convinced that self-contradicting rental terms and conditions, even with differences depending on the chosen language, are a very reliable source.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I will try emailing Hertz at Vienna airport and see what they say.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: as a Swiss (so non-EU), I can tell you that it is not true.

Comment: @JonathanReez On several occasions I have found the English versions of German websites(not specifically car rental ones) to be inaccurate or out of date resulting from translation using google translate.  I would trust the native language version more.

Comment: Guys, it is an absolute commonplace that you can rent a car in Austria (or basically "almost all" countries) WITHOUT an "IDL".  While it is worthwhile to explore head-of-a-pin issues of the language of those web sites, it is a bit daft to ignore this reality.   (As a curiosity on that last quote in this answer - I rent cars all the time from Sixt in Australia, and nobody has ever even mentioned an IDL.  {I always use a foreign license of some flavour when renting there.} )    Again - caveat - sure there could have been some dramatic recent change in policy in Austria!

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the Austrian [Führerscheingesetzt](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/GeltendeFassung.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=10012723) (Law for divers licences).
For the original text in german, see below.
<sub>The translations are mine, I am not a lawyer nor a legal translator of any sort.</sub>

> **Foreign drivers licences § 23**
>
> Sections 1 to 4 only concern persons with residence in Austria and are therefore not relevant.
>
> Section 5 states that the person must at least 18 years old. And must not stay more than 12 months in austria.
>
> (6) As proof of a permit for driving the according national drivers licence must be present. If it is not (also) written in german and does not conform to the exemplary from attachment 9 of the geneva convention or the contents of attachments 1 or 1a of the policy 91/439/EWG, ABl. Nr. 237 from August 24. 1991, version 97/26/EWG, and does not conform to the requirements of attachment 6 of the Vienna convention, the drivers licence must be accompanied by an international dirvers licence based on a convention mentioned in section 5 or with a translation by an authorized association (based on § 36 section 2 Z 3) or a foreign representation of the issuing country.

I tried to keep the translation as verbatim as possible. Any improvment are welcome.

**Conclution:**
You need to check which, if any, conventions the Australian divers licences follow. I recommend you check with one of your local car associations. They usually know the relevant regulation for travellers and can also point driving rules that are different from your home country you have to watch out for.

---

**Orignal text in german**

> **Ausländische Lenkberechtigungen § 23**
>
> Absatz 1 bis 4 betreffen Personen mit Wohnsitz in Österreich und sind hier nicht relevaten.
>
> Absatz 5 besagt, dass die Person mindestens 18 Jahre alt sein muss, und sich nicht länger als 12 Monate in Österreich aufhalten darf.
>
> (6) Als Nachweis für die Lenkberechtigung muss der entsprechende nationale Führerschein vorliegen. Wenn dieser nicht auch in deutscher Sprache abgefasst ist und auch nicht dem Muster des Anhangs 9 zum Genfer Abkommen oder den Inhalten des Anhangs 1 oder 1a der Richtlinie 91/439/EWG, ABl. Nr. 237 vom 24. August 1991 in der Fassung 97/26/EWG, entspricht und auch nicht die Anforderungen des Anhangs 6 zum Wiener Übereinkommen erfüllt, muss der Führerschein zugleich mit einem internationalen Führerschein nach einer der in Abs. 5 angeführten Vereinbarungen oder mit einer von einem gemäß § 36 Abs. 2 Z 3 ermächtigten Verein oder einer ausländischen Vertretungsbehörde des Ausstellungsstaates verfassten Übersetzung vorgewiesen werden können.

Comment: It is not relevant nor required by the law that Australia is a signatory of the Geneva Convention. The requirement is that the foreign driver's licence must adhere to the specifications in annex 9 of the convention and Australian licences do not.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: I wrongly assumed that, as Australia did sign the convention, the Australian drivers licences would adhere the to specifications. I have edited my concultion accordingly.

Comment: Fun fact: there are no "Australian" drivers licenses. Like the US, each state issues their own and they all look quite different too.