# Are unofficial International Driving Permits of any use?

Tags: usa, international-travel, driving, driving-licenses, scams

The [American Automobile Association (AAA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Automobile_Association) and the [American Automobile Touring Alliance (AATA)](http://aataidp.com/) are the [only](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/how-to-get-an-international-drivers-permit/) [organizations](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/before-you-go/driving-and-road-safety.html) that issue official [International Driving Permit (IDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit) for [US driver licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver%27s_licenses_in_the_United_States).

However, there exist some organizations that issue unofficial IDPs, such as:

- https://internationaldriversassociation.com/
- https://e-ita.org/us4/

Are such unofficial International Driving Permits of any use? I'm curious about both digital and physical unofficial IDPs.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/441/are-international-driving-licences-really-necessary-for-any-country?rq=1

Comment: I've got an official international drivers license 30+ years ago and, I've never it used for anything. My US license has always be sufficient, so I don't bring anything else.

Comment: @Hilmar thanks good to know, I'm mostly concerned about insurance, car rental and police bribes if I don't have IDP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main reasons to get an IDP:

1. You cannot legally drive a car in a foreign country without one (eg Japan).
2. Rental agencies will not rent a car to you without one.  Often the same set of countries as 1, but not always: for example, Malaysia no longer requires an IDP, but many agencies never got the memo and insist on one anyway.

A fake/unrecognized IDP will not qualify for reason 1, and you risk serious fines and potentially jail time for essentially driving without a license if caught by police.

For rental agencies, a convincing-looking fake IDP may well pass muster without exposing you to criminal penalties, so it could potentially be useful... except that if the T&C requires a real IDP, and you don't have one, this will invalidate any insurance.  So I still wouldn't risk it.

All that said, a real IDP from the AAA costs only $20, while the fakes often cost much more -- the primary target audience seems to be people without ID at all, not tourists venturing overseas.

Here's the AAA and FTC on the topic: https://www.seattletimes.com/life/travel/aaa-warns-of-fake-international-driving-permits/

Comment: Thanks! "All that said, a real IDP from the AAA costs only $20, while the fakes often cost much more -- the primary target audience seems to be people without ID at all, not tourists venturing overseas." -> another target audience is tourists already outside the US and wanting an IDP ASAP. Are digital unofficial IDPs of any use?

Comment: Of course it should be noted that very few nations actually *require* an IDP for American license holders. Most of the time its only needed if your license is not in English.

Comment: For Germany, with the exception of licences from EU, Andorra, Hong Kong, Monaco, New Zealand, San Marino, Senegal and Switzerland or holders of a IDP - a German translation is required. [Fact sheet for holders of foreign driving licences from states outside the European Union and the European Economic Area on driving licence provisions in the Federal Republic of Germany](https://www.bmvi.de/SharedDocs/DE/Anlage/StV/auslaendische-fahrerlaubnisse-merkblatt-ausserhalb-eu-und-ewr-staaten-englisch.html?dlConfirm=true)

Comment: @MarkJohnson: I've never had a problem with using my US license in Germany. I don't bring my German one anymore since it's big and unwieldy.